# Return multiple strings to ajax from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been searching for a simple solution for returning both the html and an href to AJAX from a php script, so that on clicking autocompleted search results the client is directly to another page. In short, javascript looks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".search").keyup(function () {
        var searchid = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'search=' + searchid;
        if (searchid != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#result").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

    jQuery("#result").live("click", function (e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#searchid').val(decoded);
    });
    jQuery(document).live("click", function (e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.hasClass("search")) {
            window.location.href = 'www.example.com';
        }
    });
    $('#searchid').click(function () {
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

My php goes:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if ($_POST) {
    $q = $_POST['search'];
    $sql_res = mysql_query("select name, type, image_location, linkout from search_terms where name like '%$q%' order by name LIMIT 5");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_res)) {
        $username = $row['name'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $img_loc = $row['image_location'];

        $b_username = '<strong>' . $q . '</strong>';
        $final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
        $type_class = "show";
        ?>
        <div class="show" align="left">
            <img src=<?php echo "$img_loc"; ?> style="width:50px; height:50px; float:left; margin-right:6px;" />
                 <div class="show inbox">
                <span class="name1"><?php echo ucfirst($final_username); ?></span>&nbsp;<br/><span class="name2"><a>Text here</a></span><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

I need to be able to replace the www.example.com with the href associated with each search result (from the search.php url).

The types of solutions I've read about have been around using json arrays to return the data, though so far I've had no joy implementing any. Any pointers or links to viable solutions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `json_encode()` on an array in php, and then unpacking in the js, is by far the best option. You'll have to ignore that you've "had no joy implementing any".

Comment: Also - don't send the HTML in the JSON.  Use a client-side template and send only the data that needs to go in the template.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to wrap each result block in an anchor (`a` tag) with a href attribute. If you don't want to change the markup structure like that, you can use an HTML attribute:

Give the wrapping element for each result (looks like `div.show` to me a HTML5 data attribute then reference it from the JS.

So in the php change :

```
<div class="show" align="left">
```

to be

```
<div class="show" align="left" data-url="<?= htmlentities($resultUrl); ?>">
```

In the JS change

```
var $clicked = $(e.target);
if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
window.location.href='www.example.com';
}
```

to

```
var $clicked = $(e.target).closest('div.show');

if ($clicked.length) {
    window.location.href = $clicked.attr('data-url');
}
```